# What's the quickest and cheapest way to duplicate a spellbook?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, wizard

I currently have a copy of Boccob's Blessed Book, which is fantastic, but I fear that if I lose it somehow (it gets stolen, sucked into the Astral Plane, etc.) I won't be useful as a wizard. I'd like to keep a backup somewhere, but manually copying out the current spellbook is expensive and time consuming.

Is there a spell that can quickly (and hopefully relatively cheaply) create a back-up copy of my spellbook in case things in my party go TPK?